# Can I use multiple <aside> tags for a second sidebar?

Tags: html

Can I use multiple `<aside>` tags for second sidebar?

Example:

```
<header></header>
<nav><nav>
<aside>(FIRST)
<main>
<aside>(SECOND) [or <section>?]
<footer>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can**. Try pasting it into the "direct input" part of the w3c validator for proof. You'll need it to be a full valid HTML document, e.g. something like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
 Hi
  <aside>A1</aside>
  <aside>A2</aside>
</body>
</html>
```

W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org/check

Further reading: the [W3C spec for aside](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside), neither of which specify a maximum number of this element type.