# Correct HTML5 way of defining a left/right sidebars alongside main content

Tags: css, html

I am looking at having 2 sidebars for my content with various boxes, both left and right.

With correctly written HTML5 layouts, should these be defined as aside or perhaps as divs or maybe even a section?

[Left Column,Main Site Content,Right Column]

Comment: I would go with multiple asides. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688035/can-i-use-multiple-aside-tags-for-a-second-sidebar

Comment: Depends what kind of content you put in them. Html5 element naming is about semantics, not placement :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `aside` and give a class to the each aside.

```
<aside class="left"></aside>

<section>

    <article>

    </article>

</section>

<aside class="right"></aside>
```